# SQL for XML Path using data values for node names and nesting

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

I have table data in the following format:

```
category  productkey productcode    productname  
membership  1        055385        Professional
membership  2        055575        Student
membership  3        055370        Retired
event       4        P055391       Annual Conference
event       5        PM2018        Monthly Meeting
```

The following XML format is what Im looking to achieve, notice that the second level of XML nodes from the data:

```
 <Products>
<Membership>
    <Product>
         <productcode>055385</productcode>
         <productname>Professional<productname>
    </Product>
    <Product>
         <productcode>055575</productcode>
         <productname>Student<productname>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <productcode>055370</productcode>
        <productname>Retired<productname>
    </Product>
</Membership>
<Event>
    <Product>
         <P055391>055385</productcode>
         <productname>Professional<productname>
    </Product>
    <Product>
         <productcode>Annual Conference</productcode>
         <productname>Monthly Meeting<productname>
    </Product>
</Event>
```

I have gotten close to the desired format based on this SQL:

```
 select CAST('<' + replace(b.category,' ','') + '>' +
                 CAST( (select productcode, 
                               productname
                         from @table a 
                         where a.productkey=b.productkey
                         for xml path ('Products'), TYPE) as varchar(max))
                  + '</' + replace(b.category,' ','') +'>' as xml)
 from @table b  
 for xml path (''), ROOT('Product')
```

This SQL is currently returning the "category" nodes on every product, instead of grouping the products under the "category" node:

```
 <Products>
   <Membership>
     <Product>
       <productcode>055385</productcode>
       <productname>Professional<productname>
     </Product>
  </Membership> 
  <Membership>   
     <Product>
       <productcode>055575</productcode>
       <productname>Student<productname>
     </Product>
  </Membership> 
  <Membership> 
     <Product>
       <productcode>055370</productcode>
       <productname>Retired<productname>
    </Product>
  </Membership>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be what you need:

```
 select CAST('<'+ a.Category +'>'
 + CAST((SELECT
   ProductCode, ProductName
   FROM Thing b
   WHERE b.Category = a.Category
   FOR XML path('Product'), type) as VARCHAR(MAX)) 
 + '</' + a.Category + '>'  AS XML)
 from Thing a
 GROUP BY a.Category
 ORDER BY a.Category DESC
 for xml path(''), root('Products')
```

Note that `Thing` is your table name and that you may need to add your `REPLACE` syntax back in. I was just going by the schema and data supplied.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have 2 nested XML queries: One for the `membership` records, and one for the `event` records. Something like this:

```
select 
    (   select productcode, productname
        from Mytable
        where category = 'membership' 
        for xml path('Product'), root('Membership'), type)
    ,(  select productcode, productname
        from Mytable
        where category = 'event'
        for xml path('Product'), root('Event'), type)
for xml path('Products')
```

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely one option, we were hoping to get a solution without having to hard code the category values.

Comment: If that's the case, you might be able to generate the SQL programatically, creating a separate sub-query for each distinct category value.